# local repository nmap no package nmap available

Tags: linux, centos

i am testing a local repository setup which i believe i have setup correctly. however when trying to install packages i get the error
`no package nmap available`
running yum repolist returns the following

```
repo id                            repo name                            status
loacl                              loacl repo                             347
```

I have also tried installing ntp but get the same error.
can you advise as to why i am getting no package nmap available. Is it because the source DVD which was a minimal CD install DVD does not contain this package.

Please advise

Thanks

Rehan Miah

Comment: If nmap is not in your additional repo then you cannot install it from there. You did not say if nmap is in that repo or not.

Comment: How do I check if the package is in the repo

Comment: With `ls` you can list the files. If it is larger you can use `find . -name nmap*`

Comment: which folder do i ls the contents of /repodata has different xml file the /packages folder only list packages which seem installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status refers to the number of packages that are available on the source repository. i downloaded the full DVD and copied the contents to use this as the source repository. this had a status of around 3500. the package installed without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing using

```
yum install nmap-frontend
```

It worked for me on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)

You can testing using like `nmap 25 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`